# Linux-headers-5.10.0-21-amd64 not found debian 11

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, dual-boot, macintosh, linux-headers

I flashed a Debian image from [debian official DVD amd64](https://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/) into a live USB and installed it on a dual boot into my MacBook air 2020 intel core i7 following [this tutorial](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-linux-macbook-pro/). While installing, the FAT32 formatted partition couldn't be mounted as root, so I formatted the partition as ext4 file and the installation was successful.

After the installation, my trackpad, keyboard, WIFI, and bluetooth were not working. So I was following [this Stackoverflow answer](https://superuser.com/a/1503589) to install the applespi driver in an effort to get the trackpad and keyboard working, but I got an error after running the last command `dkms install -m applespi -v 0.1`. The error message

```
Your kernel headers for kernel 5.10.0-21-amd64 cannot be found. Please install the linux-headers-5.10.0-21-amd64 package or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
```

`uname -r` output is `5.10.0-21-amd64`
`apt search linux-headers-$(uname -r)` output is

```
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
```

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` output is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.10.0-21-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob linux-headers-5.10.0-21-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by regex linux-headers-5.10.0-21-amd64
```

I upgraded my kernel to 6.0.0-0.deb11.6-amd64 and the error still occurs (`Unable to locate package linux-headers-6.0.0-0.deb11.6-amd64`)

How can I install the linux headers for my kernel version?

Answer (score 1):

I added `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main` to my /etc/apt/sources.list, and run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo reboot
```

Though I got another error on running `dkms install -m applespi -v 0.1` but that's another issue.