# Keyboard, trackpad, wifi and bluetooth not working after debian installed on macbook

Tags: linux, debian, macintosh

I installed Debian bullseye on my MacBook Air 2020 Corei7 laptop. During and after installation, the keyboard, trackpad, WIFI, and bluetooth were not working. I followed [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1503589) in an effort to partly resolve the issue but run into some linux-headers file not been found issue as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/736003/561265). I resolved that issue but run into another error `kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...` whenever I run the command `dkms install -m applespi -v 0.1` as instructed [in this Stackoverflow answer](https://superuser.com/a/1503589).

I later found out the error may be because applespi v0.1 is no longer compatible with new linux kernel versions. I made sure I installed all missing firmware reported by `update-initramfs -u`, yet the keyboard, trackpad, WIFI, and bluetooth were still not working.

How do I make my keyboard, trackpad, WIFI and bluetooth work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out I must follow the post-installation instructions described [here](https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/postinstall/#installing-modules) because my MacBook is a T2 Macbook.

I'd advise to read [state of features](https://wiki.t2linux.org/state/) to further help decide if it's actually worth dual-booting Linux on your T2 Macbook machine